# Transform an array into a matrix with its elements filling the upper triangle of matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

I want to convert array into matrix filling the upper triangle of matrix in one of the following manners

[image: array to matrix]

In ***tf.contrib.distributions.fill_triangular***, the triangular matrix elements are filled in a clockwise spiral, including the diagonal elements. I tried following set of commands, but it didn’t work.

```
x = placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 891])
dummy_expected_output = placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 42, 42])
ones = tf.ones_like(dummy_expected_output) #size of the output matrix 
mask_a = tf.matrix_band_part(ones, 0, -1)  # Upper triangular matrix of 0s and 1s
mask_b = tf.matrix_band_part(ones, 0, 0)  # Diagonal matrix of 0s and 1s
mask = tf.subtract(mask_a, mask_b) # Mask of upper triangle above diagonal
zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
non_zero = tf.not_equal(ones, zero) #Conversion of mask to Boolean matrix

indices = tf.cast(tf.where(non_zero),dtype=tf.int64) # Extracting the indices of upper triangle elements

zeros = tf.zeros_like(dummy_expected_output) #size of the output matrix
out = tf.add(zeros, tf.sparse_to_dense(indices,tf.cast(tf.shape(zeros),dtype=tf.int64), tf.reshape(x,[-1]), default_value=0))
```

It results in error “***Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: [None]. Consider casting elements to a supported type***”. I tried casting but it didn’t work. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I see this error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: WhereOp : Unhandled input dimensions: 0` Is your `x` like this ? `x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

Comment: 'x' is another placeholder which is a 1d array/vector that is used to fill the matrix. I think the problem is that being a placeholder it can have variable batch size. The variability of batch size ends up with this error. It works fine when I test with a constant tensor (like the one you mentioned). I still didn't find a solution yet

Comment: Please update your question with details from you comment.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I think you feed the placeholder ? Right ?

Comment: Yes I do because I can't figure out how to handle "batch size" of 1D array for converting it into matrix. For a constant tensor the code works fine but not for placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your output patterns is obtained by slightly refactoring your code.

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ones = tf.ones((4,4),dtype=tf.int64) #size of the output matrix
mask_a = tf.matrix_band_part(ones, 0, -1)  # Upper triangular matrix of 0s and 1s
mask_b = tf.matrix_band_part(ones, 0, 0)  # Diagonal matrix of 0s and 1s
mask = tf.subtract(mask_a, mask_b) # Mask of upper triangle above diagonal

zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64)
non_zero = tf.not_equal(mask, zero) #Conversion of mask to Boolean matrix
sess.run(non_zero)
indices = tf.where(non_zero) # Extracting the indices of upper trainagle elements

out = tf.SparseTensor(indices,x,dense_shape=tf.cast((4,4),dtype=tf.int64))
dense = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(out)
dense = tf.print(dense, [dense], summarize=100)
sess.run(dense)
```

Output is this.

```
[[0 1 2 3]
 [0 0 4 5]
 [0 0 0 6]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: 'x' is a placeholder which is a 1d array/vector that is used to fill the matrix. The code works fine when a constant tensor is declared. I am unable to find out a solution to handle the variable batch size of 'x'. I tried with "InteractiveSession" but it didn't work

Comment: Awesome answer, and it having no upvotes is extremely underrated IMO.